# Handling UTF-8 strings in C# web service

Tags: .net, string, web-services, encoding, utf-8

I created a simple web service client using the C# tool wsdl.exe. It works fine except for one thing. It seems that UTF-8 strings returned in response are converted to ASCII. Using SOAPUI I can see normal UTF-8 encoded strings being returned by the web service. But when I debug the response I received the UTF-8 content seems to have already been converted to ASCII and is completely garbled. Where I should see a string containing Japanese characters I'm seeing a list of '?'.

1. Is there a way to convert back the string to Unicode so that seen in the debugger is the original response string ?
2. Is there a way to prevent the string from getting garbled in the service response?

Comment: What are you debugging it with? It could be that it works fine, but the debugging code/app/whatever is messing it up after the fact.

Comment: Good point. I'm using Visual Studio C# Express 2010. I have been able to play around with proper Unicode string and they appear fine.

Comment: Are you actually encoding the strings? 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding.aspx#Y2800

Comment: If you have "?" characters, it's not just garbled, you've lost the data. Those literally are "?" characters.

Comment: If you've seen data being correctly sent from the webservice then it's likely that it is just the client side that's unable to handle UTF8 correctly. Are you using the command line to view output? Try displaying the response in a MessageBox instead.

Comment: @[user473098] Instead of sending the data as a string, try sending the data as a byte array and convert it to the same encoding on the client side.

Comment: How exactly have you implemented your web service client? Can you show some code? If you use standard Microsoft tools and libraries (such as WCF), you shouldn't have any problems with UTF-8 strings unless the web service has a problem, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you are actually encoding the strings as per the documentation @Sam provided:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

class UTF8EncodingExample {
    public static void Main() {
        // Create a UTF-8 encoding.
        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();

        // A Unicode string with two characters outside an 8-bit code range.
        String unicodeString =
            "This unicode string contains two characters " +
            "with codes outside an 8-bit code range, " +
            "Pi (\u03a0) and Sigma (\u03a3).";
        Console.WriteLine("Original string:");
        Console.WriteLine(unicodeString);

        // Encode the string.
        Byte[] encodedBytes = utf8.GetBytes(unicodeString);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Encoded bytes:");
        foreach (Byte b in encodedBytes) {
            Console.Write("[{0}]", b);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Decode bytes back to string.
        // Notice Pi and Sigma characters are still present.
        String decodedString = utf8.GetString(encodedBytes);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Decoded bytes:");
        Console.WriteLine(decodedString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending the data as a string, try sending the data as a byte array and convert it to the same encoding on the client side.